# A template function crashes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I define following template function, which applies a function f on each element of an array

```
template <typename X, typename Y, size_t n>     
array <Y, n> lod (const function <Y (const X)> f, const array <X, n> w)
{
   array <Y, n> l;
   for (GLint i = 0; i = i + 1; i < n)
      l [i] = f (w [i]);
   return l;
}
```

As an example of f, I define a function "add a"

```
template <typename X>
function <X (const X)> ae (const X a)
{
   return [a] (const X x)
   {
      return x + a;
   };
}
```

Then I try to apply it

```
const array <ivec3, 12> oblad = {ivec3 (0, 2, 1), ivec3 (0, 3, 2), ivec3 (0, 1, 5), ivec3 (0, 5, 4),
                                ivec3 (1, 2, 6), ivec3 (1, 6, 5), ivec3 (2, 3, 7), ivec3 (2, 7, 6),
                                ivec3 (3, 0, 4), ivec3 (3, 4, 7), ivec3 (4, 5, 6), ivec3 (4, 6, 7)};

array <ivec3, 12> w = lod (ae (ivec3 (1)), oblad);
```

The program compiles just fine, however crashes upon execution.

Comment: Your loop writes out of bounds of the array, once `i` reaches `n`. You probably meant `for (GLint i = 0; i < n; ++i)`

Comment: That's not how loops work. Please consult any elementary text book on C++.

Comment: voting to close as typo (messing up the for loop condition order)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you are passing arrays around by value, the reason for the crash is simple:

```
for (GLint i = 0; i = i + 1; i < n)
```

This should be

```
for (GLint i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1)
```

your version of the loop is conditional on `i = i + 1` which returns true for all values of `i` which don't wrap-around to `0` when adding 1. At the end of each loop you were performing the test `i < n` but the result was ignored.

-- Edit --

According to [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter) the syntax for a for loop is:

```
for ( init-statement conditionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

`conditionopt` is the conditional tested for at the *start* of each iteration of the loop, `expressionopt` is an optional expression executed at the *end* of every iteration.

Comment: Would have loved to edit your code but I can't since it's just one ';' missing in your edit :(

Comment: @Zouch That was a copy & paste from the standard: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoIctv5uIJy5hLM8nJIEjuQHOu_fgQ

Comment: Rolled back - the standard is actually correct (unsurprisingly), the definition of *for-init-statement* includes that it ends in a semicolon